# Mysql If exists fails when two simultanious request. How to fix this issue?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have written a code to insert a query when only the particular condition does not exist but it fails only when two simultaneous requests come from the browser. So duplicate entry occur in the database. I used this in a stored procedure.

Example:

```
if not exists(select * from tblUser where Email=dEmail and status=2) then
   insert into tbluser(Name,Email,Status) values (dName,dEmail,dStatus);
else
   Update tblUser set Name=dName where Email=dEmail and status=2;
end if;
```

Please tell me a good solution.

Comment: My MySQL version **5.6.37**

Comment: What do you mean "it fails"? Is there an error? If so, what is the error? If not, describe the problem. Also, is the stored proc the actual code that has the problem or a simulation? If a simulation, please show the actual code.

Comment: Use `select ... for update`; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: **Duplicate entries** are added to the table tblUser. @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

You can add a composite unique key to your table to prevent duplicates.

```
ALTER TABLE `tblUser ` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(Email,Status);
```

Comment: It may give the exception, I don't want that.

Comment: Exceptions are not errors so you can handle them appropriately in your application.

Comment: I will not delete the email address in the database. I will change the status to 0 instead of deleting them. so I cannot add unique_index